# Sending attachment does not work always

Tags: android, email-attachments

Sometimes I see the emails without attachment.

I suspect that this happens when the file size grows larger than the handler.

My send code -

```
        Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Device Logs");

        email.setType("text/plain");

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getEmailContents());

        File file = writeLogFile();

        ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        uriList.add(uri);

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

The File code -

```
public File writeLogFile()
        {

            if(builder != null)
            {
                for(int i =0;i <receiptlist.size();i++)
                {
                    builder.append(receiptlist.get(i) + "\n");
                }
            }

            //to create a Text file name "logcat.txt" in SDCard  
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myLogcat");  

            if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();  

            File file = new File(dir, "logcat.txt");

            try {    
                  //to write logcat in text file  
                  FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);  
                  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);   

                    // Write the string to the file  
                    osw.write(builder.toString());              
                    osw.flush();  
                    osw.close();  
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
                  e.printStackTrace();  
                 } catch (IOException e) {  
                  e.printStackTrace();  
                 }

                return file;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Resolved** - I was deleting the file at `onDestroy()`.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();  
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
        String  sdPath = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myLogcat";  

        File sdDir = new File(sdPath);

        if(sdDir.exists())
            deleteRecursive(sdDir);
    }
```

So if user is in activity and sends the file then it is sent but if user leaves the activity and comes back and sends then it isn't sent because leaving the activity has deleted the file already.